# "ReferenceError: require is not defined" when importing a js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, require

This is an old question that has been asked many times. I have tried all the solutions but nothing works.

I am using `MongDB` and want the names of users stored in the database to be displayed on the main page as a list even after closing and reopening the browser. When I import `phones.js` in `code.js`, I get :

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

Thus, I can't use the database to display the names. I understand that browsers don't have the `require` method defined, Node.js does. But is there a turnaround to this?

`app.js` is in main directory ( . / )

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Phones = require('./models/phones');
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');

//...MongoDB connection

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//...creating endpoints
```

`phones.js` is in ./models/phones.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//...create Schema

const Phones = mongoose.model('Phones', phonesSchema);
module.exports = Phones;
```

`code.js` in ./public/code.js

```
const Phones = require('../models/phones.js');
console.log(Phones.find({}));

//...create an 'li' for each number and append it to 'ul'
```

`index.html` in ./public/index.html

```
<script src="code.js" ></script>
```

I have used browserify : `browserify app.js -r bundle.js` and I get a huge error.

If there's another approach to display on a page the names stored in the database even after closing the browser it will be accepted as the solution also.

Comment: Are you bundling code so you can run it in the browser?  If so, you can't run things like mongoose or mongodb in the browser.  They only run on the server.

Comment: Are you using webpack to build your project ?

Comment: @Lk77 no i'm not. should I? i've never used it before

Comment: then what are you using to build your project ?

Comment: @jfriend00 true but I need to find a way to display the phone numbers even after closing and reopening the browser.

Comment: @Lk77 i'm using express. and i have tried browserify as mentioned but still wasn't working

Comment: are you trying to load your project on your brower ? it that case it wont work

Comment: @Lk77 yes exactly. I want to be able to perform actions such as delete, add, modify phone numbers from the browser

Comment: you won't be able to do that, you need to make a request to your server, using express in your case with node.js

Comment: I have already figured how to do these operations (delete, add, etc.). Only thing left is to display phone numbers on the web page after closing the browser. Because when I add a phone number for example, it adds it to the DB and displays it on the screen. But when I close the browser and reopen it, the number stays in the DB of course but it is not displayed on the web page anymore.